# Decode an App Engine Blobkey to a Google Cloud Storage Filename

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, google-cloud-storage

I've got a database full of BlobKeys that were previously uploaded through the standard Google App Engine [create_upload_url()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions#create_upload_url) process, and each of the uploads went to the same Google Cloud Storage bucket by setting the `gs_bucket_name` argument.

What I'd like to do is be able to decode the existing blobkeys so I can get their Google Cloud Storage filenames. I understand that I ***could*** have been using the [gs_object_name](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/fileinfoclass#FileInfo_gs_object_name) property from the [FileInfo class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/fileinfoclass), except:

> You must save the gs_object_name yourself in your upload handler or
>   this data will be lost. (The other metadata for the object in GCS is stored 
>   in GCS automatically, so you don't need to save that in your upload handler.

Meaning `gs_object_name` property is only available in the upload handler, and if I haven't been saving it at that time then its lost.

Also, [create_gs_key()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions#create_gs_key) doesn't do the trick because it instead takes a google storage filename and creates a blobkey.

So, how can I take a blobkey that was previously uploaded to a Google Cloud Storage bucket through app engine, and get it's Google Cloud Storage filename? (python)

Comment: To my knowledge you can only rewrite the blob, that means reading it byte by byte and writing it again to the cloudstorage similar to renaming a cloudstorage file, but this time saving the cloudstorage path instead of the blobkey. BlobKeys saving cloudstorage objects seem to be in "monkeypatch" state. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697418/programmatically-emulating-gsutil-mv-on-appengine-cloudstorage-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the cloudstorage filename only in the upload handler (fileInfo.gs_object_name) and store it in your database. After that it is lost and it seems not to be preserved in BlobInfo or other metadata structures.

> Google says: Unlike BlobInfo metadata FileInfo metadata is not
>   persisted to datastore. (There is no blob key either, but you can
>   create one later if needed by calling create_gs_key.) You must save
>   the gs_object_name yourself in your upload handler or this data will
>   be lost.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/fileinfoclass

Update: I was able to decode a SDK-BlobKey in Blobstore-Viewer: "encoded_gs_file:base64-encoded-filename-here". However the real thing is not base64 encoded.

create_gs_key(filename, rpc=None) ... Google says: "Returns an encrypted blob key as a string." Does anyone have a guess why this is encrypted?

Comment: Probably encrypted because it includes the access token.

Answer (score 2):

From the statement in the docs, it looks like the generated GCS filenames are lost.  You'll have to use gsutil to manually browse your bucket.

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls

Answer (score 0):

If you have blobKeys you can use: ImagesServiceFactory.[makeImageFromBlob](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/IImagesServiceFactory.html#makeImageFromBlob)