# How to get type of the file from the Google Cloud Storage based on its blobkey?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have the blobkey of the file stored in the Google Cloud Storage. This is the only information I have. Having this information, I can read the file (but I don't know and can not get its filename). Is there any way to get the file type or read its metadata (`Content type`, for ex., `image/jpeg`) either from the file content or from the Google Cloud Storage? It will allow me to assign correct file extensions (filename is not so important, so standard names like `noname.jpg`, `noname.png`, `noname.pdf` will be OK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the filename or other properties from the blob_key. You need a BlobInfo object. GCS files do not have a BlobInfo object. You have to create your own.

Example: https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-blobstore-python

Comment: Looking at your code, I see that you use additional `BlobFiles` class to store files metadata and filename. I can not do easily since huge code and database modifications would be required. Is there any way to create BlobInfo object manually (when `create_gs_key` is used)? I am also thinking about guessing the mime type based on file content (something like `MimeTypes.read(filename)`).

Comment: I also tried to decode the key, created by `create_gs_key` function, looking at appengine source code (https://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn-history/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/blobstore/blobstore_stub.py and https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/blobstore/blobstore#create_gs_key), but failed to understand what kind of the token is used there in addition to base64 encoding (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19655087/604388). So, finally I had to follow your approach and to store filenames and filetypes in the separate NDB properties ;(.

Comment: I've raised an issue https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12132 to either support BlobInfo for GCS files or to implement function list `get_gs_filename_from_blobkey'.

Answer (score 1):

But GCS files have a stat object that stores at least size, md5, content_type and metadata (Dict that contains any user-specified metadata from the x-goog-meta- header). Although you cannot reach it with the BlobKey alone **on the real server** (it works on the SDK, as buckets are emulated by blobstore there!).

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/gcsfilestat_class

Comment: Again, you should know file name to get such data - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#stat

Comment: That is correct. I wanted to point out that on the SDK getting the BlobInfo works, but on the real server it fails (surprise!). IMO storing GCS blobs in BlobKeys is a Hack-Fix by Google, not a well engineered system.